# C changing a pointer in a function

Tags: c, pointers, heap-corruption

I want to write a function that processes a string that looks like this:

> |1,2,3,4|(1->2),(2->3),(3->1)|

The result should be a breaking down of the string into these strings:

> - 1
> - 2
> - 3
> - 4
> - (1->2)
> - (2->3)
> - (3->2)

This is my code:

```
int processPart(char*** dest, char* from) //Processes a half at a time
{
    int len = 0;
    char* cutout = strtok(from, ",");
    while(cutout)
    {
        (*dest) = (char**)realloc(dest, (len + 1) * sizeof(char*)); <<<<<<<
        (*dest)[len] = (char*)calloc(strlen(cutout) + 1, sizeof(char));
        memcpy((*dest)[len], cutout, strlen(cutout));
        cutout = strtok(NULL, ",");
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

void processInput(char*** vertices, char*** edges, char* input, int* sizev, int* sizee)
{
    int vlen = 0, elen = 0;
    char* string = input + 1;
    char* raw_vertices;
    char* raw_edges;
    string[strlen(string)] = '\0';
    raw_vertices = strtok(string, "|");
    raw_edges = strtok(NULL, "|");
    *sizev = processPart(vertices, raw_vertices); //First the vertices
    *sizee = processPart(edges, raw_edges); //Then the edges
}

int main()
{
    char* in = stInput(); //input function
    char** c = NULL, **b = NULL;
    int a, d, i;
    processInput(&c, &b, in, &a, &d);
    for(i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", c[i]);
    }
    printf("++++++++++++++++");
    for(i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", b[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get a corruption of the heap at the line marked by <<<<<<<

Anyone knows what my mistake is?

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: I did spot the error - it's on a particular line, as mentioned. I just don't know what is the mistake and how to do it right.

Comment: You spotted a *symptom*, for sure.  But now you need to work backwards to identify the actual cause of that symptom.

Answer (score 1):

In the erroneous line

```
        (*dest) = (char**)realloc(dest, (len + 1) * sizeof(char*));
```

a `*` is missing before the `dest` argument. You could have spotted this easier if you hadn't cluttered the expression with the useless cast. I'd write

```
        *dest = realloc(*dest, (len + 1) * sizeof**dest);
```

- that way we can see better the matching of first argument and left operand of the assignment.